# Sed to delete eveything between two non alpha numeric chars

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have the following string:

```
com.advantco.aws.core;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.aws.core.adapter;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.aws.core.adapter.channelreader.receiver;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.aws.core.adapter.channelreader.sender;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.aws.core.service;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.aws.core.service.s3;version="[1.0,2)"
```

Need to remove everything after the `;version` al the way till `",`
Basically need to get only all the package names for the output to be like

```
com.advantco.aws.core 
com.advantco.aws.core.adapter 
com.advantco.aws.core.adapter.channelreader.receiver
...
```

I am trying this

```
sed -e's/.;*.[",]//g'
```

but it only gives me

```
com.adntco.aws.core;versio[1,com.adntco.aws.core.adapter;versio[1
```

I need to match multiple matches in one line.
What am I doing wrong here?

Update One:
Some of the packages are missing the import version, some of the packages have other sub attributes instead of version, like, com.advantco.core;optiona=true, so basically I want everything removed after the ; and till the last comma (i.e there could be multiple commas after the semicolon or no semi colon and just one comma.).

example

```
com.advantco.aws.core;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.aws.core.adapter,com.advantco.aws.core.adapter.channelreader.receiver;version=false,com.advantco.aws.core.adapter.channelreader.sender;optional=true,com.advantco.aws.core.service;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.aws.core.service.s3;version="[1.0,2)"
```

Added other details to individual comments

**Edge Test Case** This is failing for some of my imports so the edge test case for examples in places where you have resolution=optional instead of version..

```
com.advantco.base.hci.af.util;version="[1.0,2)", javax.security.auth.x500;resolution:=optional,com.advantco.base.hci.variablesubstitution,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution,com.advantco.suarcrm.core.adapter;version="1.0,2)",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,javax.naming.directory;resolution:=optional
```

**Expected Output**

```
com.advantco.base.hci.af.util
javax.security.auth.x500
com.advantco.base.hci.variablesubstitution
com.advantco.base.logging
com.advantco.base.mime
com.advantco.base.net
com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution
com.advantco.suarcrm.core.adapter
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error
javax.naming.directory
```

**EDGE Test Case 2 Still open**

The sample manifest file looks exactly like this, @anubhavas answer is the closest but it also captures the export packages that follow which need not be captured. Also the last line of import and the second line of export get merged creating eronous results.

```
Bnd-LastModified: 1494408636933
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Import-Package: com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advant
 co.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitu
 tion,com.advantco.rest,com.advantco.rest.auth,com.advantco.rest.auth.
 oauth2,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.adapter,
 com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.meta
 data,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.
 auth,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c
 ore.rest.op,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op.v10,com.advantco.sugar
 crm.core.rest.parser,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object,co
 m.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.r
 est.service,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result,com.advantco.sugarcrm.c
 ore.result.v10,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.service,com.advantco.sugarc
 rm.core.util,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml,javax.activation,javax.cr
 ypto,javax.crypto.spec,javax.mail,javax.xml.bind,javax.xml.parsers,ja
 vax.xml.stream,javax.xml.transform,javax.xml.transform.dom,javax.xml.
 transform.stream,org.apache.commons.codec.binary,org.apache.commons.c
 ollections4.map,org.apache.commons.httpclient,org.apache.commons.http
 client.util,org.json
Require-Capability: osgi.ee;filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.6))"
Tool: Bnd-3.3.0.201609221906
Export-Package: com.advantco.sugarcrm.core;uses:="com.advantco.base.lo
 gging,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object";version="1.0.0",com.advantco
 .sugarcrm.core.adapter;uses:="com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.log
 ging,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco
 .sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata";ver
 sion="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error;version="1.0.0",com.adv
 antco.sugarcrm.core.iface;uses:="com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.object";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm
 .core.object;uses:="com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.mime,com.adva
 ntco.base.net,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.
 core.iface,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata,com.advantco.su
 garcrm.core.rest.parser.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.util";versi
 on="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata;uses:="com.adva
 ntco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.obje
 ct";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest;uses:="com.advant
 co.base.logging,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core
 .object";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.auth;uses:="
 com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.rest.auth.oauth2,com.advantco.
 sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.
 core.object";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata
 ;uses:="com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.adva
 ntco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advant
 co.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata,org.json";version="1.0.0",com.advant
 co.sugarcrm.core.rest.op;uses:="com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.l
 ogging,com.advantco.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.rest
 ,com.advantco.rest.auth.oauth2,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.a
 dvantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metada
 ta,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.pa
 rser.object,org.json";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest
 .op.v10;uses:="com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.base.mime,com.a
 dvantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.adv
 antco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op,org.json";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.su
 garcrm.core.rest.parser;uses:="com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco
 .sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.s
 ugarcrm.core.rest";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.pa
 rser.chn;uses:="com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.
 error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.re
 st.parser";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.obj
 ect;version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml;uses:=
 "com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advan
 tco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata,c
 om.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest
 .parser.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml";version="1.0.0",com.ad
 vantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.service;uses:="com.advantco.base.logging,co
 m.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface,com.a
 dvantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest";version
 ="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result;uses:="com.advantco.base.l
 ogging,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,co
 m.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,javax.xml.stream";version="1.0.0",com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.result.v10;uses:="com.advantco.base.logging,c
 om.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.re
 sult,javax.xml.stream";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.ser
 vice;uses:="com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.ifac
 e,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sug
 arcrm.core.test;uses:="com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantco.
 sugarcrm.core.object";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.util
 ;uses:="com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.mime,com.advantco.rest,co
 m.advantco.sugarcrm.core,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,com.advantc
 o.sugarcrm.core.object,com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata,com
 .advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object,javax.activation,javax.xml
 .stream,org.json";version="1.0.0",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml;uses
 :="com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error";version="1.0.0"
Bundle-Name: sugarcrm-core
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_71
```

Output

```
com.advantco.base
com.advantco.base.logging
com.advantco.base.mime
com.advantco.base.net
com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution
com.advantco.rest
com.advantco.rest.auth
com.advantco.rest.auth.oauth2
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.adapter
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.iface
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.object.metadata
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.auth
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.metadata
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.op.v10
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.object
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.parser.xml
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.rest.service
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.result.v10
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.service
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.util
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.xml
javax.activation
javax.crypto
javax.crypto.spec
javax.mail
javax.xml.bind
javax.xml.parsers
javax.xml.stream
javax.xml.transform
javax.xml.transform.dom
javax.xml.transform.stream
org.apache.commons.codec.binary
org.apache.commons.collections4.map
org.apache.commons.httpclient
org.apache.commons.httpclient.util
org.json
```

Comment: Please wrap up your samples of input and output in code tags, since it is not clear without it. Use `{}` button.

Comment: Added edge test cases in description, I only go these exceptions once I ran the scripts on a wider set of inputs

Comment: must have missed them, I was manually typing the expected output, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Don't place full file here, just show what input are you supplying to my sed command and what is expected output?

Comment: are the lines wrapped as it is posted in the question for Export package?. please share the expected output..

Comment: The Impor/Export or any attribute Headers follow a new line and space delimited patters, the lines are exactly as they appear, new line delimited.

Comment: Yeah, I was reading from import package and all new lines that were followed by a space till I got a new line that was not followed by space essentially terminating the import grep which is now failing, I will upvote your answer but would be glad if you could help me with read the read statement.

Comment: @anubhava Added the input manifest file and the output expected, so basically need to pasre the import package to one line before passing to your solution.

Comment: ok you may use this: `sed -E 's/.*Package: //; s/;([^;"]*"[^"]*")*[^;,]*((,) *){0,1}/\3/g; s/,/\n/g' <<< "$str"`

Comment: Dosen't work, captures bundle name and bundle version attribute as well, earlier I was using "sed -n -e '/Import-Package/,/[A-Z]/ p'" to read import package and read all the way till new Capital letter, but then there is an attribute header "uri:" which starts with small letter so it was picking that up as well so now need something that picks Import-Package and then continues to read till finds newline followed by space which will only stop once it finds a new attribute field, capital or small.

Comment: You are not getting it. You cannot throw complete manifest file to sed command, It is supposed to work on line like this: **`str='Import-Package: com.advantco.base,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution,com.advantco.rest,com.advantco.rest.auth,com.advantco.rest.auth.oauth2,com'`**

Comment: So I am basically piping thru multiple find, grep and seds and It worked with the only exception of the small uri attribute, not only that, I am throwing 70MB worth of Manifests at it and it work s for 99% cases, I though Grepping all lines which start with a space after Import-Package till a newline with no space was the only puzzle left.

Comment: This almost works like a charm other than for tha one uri attribute
for file in $(cat jarlist); do unzip -q -c $file META-INF/MANIFEST.MF > $file.mf; echo ''; echo ''; echo $file.mf; echo ''; echo ''; cat $file.mf | sed -n -e '/Import-Package/,/[A-Z]/ p'| sed -e '$d' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' ' | sed -E 's/;([^;"]*"[^"]*")*[^;,]*((,) *){0,1}/\3/g; s/,/\n/g'; done

Comment: Simple version of the command above which only handles the manifest
cat $file.mf | sed -n -e '/Import-Package/,/[A-Z]/ p'| sed -e '$d' | tr -d '\n' | tr -d ' ' | sed -E 's/;([^;"]*"[^"]*")*[^;,]*((,) *){0,1}/\3/g; s/,/\n/g';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this **`gnu sed`**:

```
sed -E 's/;([^;"]*"[^"]*")*[^;,]*((,) *){0,1}/\3/g; s/,/\n/g' <<< "$str"
```

RegEx Details:

**1st substitution:**

- `;`: Match literal `;`
- `([^;"]*"[^"]*")*`: Match 0 or more strings enclosed in double quotes
- `[^;,]*`: Match 0+ characters that are not `;` and `,`
- `((,) *){0,1}`: Match optional comma followed by 0+ spaces. Captures comma in 3rd capture group
- `\3`: In replacement puts 3rd capture group back which is comma or empty string

**2nd substitution:**

- `s/,/\n/g`: Replaces all commas with newline

**Example: 1**

```
com.advantco.aws.core
com.advantco.aws.core.adapter
com.advantco.aws.core.adapter.channelreader.receiver
com.advantco.aws.core.adapter.channelreader.sender
com.advantco.aws.core.service
com.advantco.aws.core.service.s3
```

**Example: 2**

```
com.advantco.base.hci.af.util
javax.security.auth.x500
com.advantco.base.hci.variablesubstitution
com.advantco.base.logging
com.advantco.base.mime
com.advantco.base.net
com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution
com.advantco.suarcrm.core.adapter
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error
javax.naming.directory
```

Comment: please see update one on why I wanted everything between ; and comma removed if anything after ; is present and not just version.

Comment: Yes, 3) is not expected.

Comment: this failes for mixed cases where one import may have a version while the other does not, the 3) is probably because I am using this over git bash, here is the test case:
com.advantco.base.hci.af.util;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.base.hci.variablesubstitution;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.base.mime,com.adv antco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution,com.advantco.su garcrm.core.adapter;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.sgarcrm.core.error

Comment: Added edge test cases in description, I only go these exceptions once I ran the scripts on a wider set of inputs

Comment: why do we have the {0,1}/\3/, also could you explain the script so that I can understand the underlying logic please?

Comment: this also captures any other export statements that follow and fails.
Added test case two to explain

Answer (score 2):

***EDIT:*** Since OP has posted a bit different output so adding this solution now.

```
awk '{while(match($0,/com\.[^;]*/)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);$0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)}}'   Input_file
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/;[^)]*)//g;s/)",/ /g;s/",$//;s/",/\n/g'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
com.adntco.aws.core
com.adntco.aws.core.adapter
```

Comment: Based on your idea, there is this shorter version: `sed 's/;[^)]*)",/\n/g; s/;version=.*)"$//g'`

Comment: @Jayjargot, thanks for letting me know, I thought it but it was entering a new line at last so I didn't use it.

Comment: please see update one on why I wanted everything between ; and comma removed if anything after ; is present and not just version.

Comment: @Sameer, could you please check my EDIT solution now and let me know if this helps you? It is giving same output as per your shown sample.

Comment: why the /com. there are imports without any com in it.

Comment: @Sameer, could you please try `sed 's/;[^)]*)//g;s/)",/ /g;s/",$//;s/",/\n/g;s/"$//'  Input_file` once and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 This fails for mixed inputs like, where you have version in one package and not in the other. com.advantco.base.hci.variablesubstitution;version="[1.0,2)",com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.base.mime

Comment: Added edge test cases in description, I only go these exceptions once I ran the scripts on a wider set of inputs

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl

```
> export data=$(cat sameer.log )
> cat sameer.log
com.advantco.base.hci.af.util;version="[1.0,2)", javax.security.auth.x500;resolution:=optional,com.advantco.base.hci.variablesubstitution,com.advantco.base.logging,com.advantco.base.mime,com.advantco.base.net,com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution,com.advantco.suarcrm.core.adapter;version="1.0,2)",com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error,javax.naming.directory;resolution:=optional
>
> perl -lne 's/resolution:=optional//g;s/version=.+?\"//g;for(split(/[;, ]/)){ print if not /^\s*$/ } ' <<< "$data"
com.advantco.base.hci.af.util
javax.security.auth.x500
com.advantco.base.hci.variablesubstitution
com.advantco.base.logging
com.advantco.base.mime
com.advantco.base.net
com.advantco.base.variablesubstitution
com.advantco.suarcrm.core.adapter
com.advantco.sugarcrm.core.error
javax.naming.directory
>
```

Comment: cant hardcode any attribute name. See edge case 2 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me :

```
echo 'com.adntco.aws.core;version="[1.0,2)",com.adntco.aws.core.adapter;version="[1.0,2)",' | tr ';' '\n' | sed 's/version="[^"]*",//g' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Regards!

Comment: Some of the packages don't have the version flag, some have different attributes instead of version.

Comment: please see update one on why I wanted everything between ; and comma removed if anything after ; is present and not just version.

Comment: Added edge test cases in description, I only go these exceptions once I ran the scripts on a wider set of inputs